# Clean code - what should I do to avoid passing two arguments

Tags: optimization

I recently read "clean code" from Robert C.Martin and some concepts are unclear for me.
I have this object

```
export class SyncErrorList{
    constructor(
        public SignatureErrors: SignatureSyncError[],
        public ArErrors: ARSyncError[],
        public EnrSyncError: EnrSyncError[]
    ){}
}
```

I want to make a function that delete a "syncerror" from a list. I want to pass this functions the type of list and the index, is it a bad design because the function wil take two arguments ?

```
deleteErrorByErrorAndIndex(SyncError: DocSyncError, index: number){
    if(SyncError instanceof SignatureSyncError){
        this.SignatureErrors.splice(index, 1);
    }

    if(SyncError instanceof ARSyncError){
        this.ArErrors.splice(index, 1);
    }


    if(SyncError instanceof EnrSyncError){
        this.EnrSyncError.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

It's hard for me to determine when a function that takes two parameters is "acceptable". I technically could just pass the syncerror and search for it in the list to get the index, but it would be less optimized, is my case one of the cases it would be acceptable ? If not, what should I do ?

Comment: I'd rename the function to `deleteErrorByIndex`, but nothing wrong with (these) two params

Comment: “is it a bad design because the function wil take two arguments ?” — **No**. If Bob Martin says otherwise he’s wrong. As he often is.

Comment: that's not exactly what he says, he says it should be avoided, but I don't know when it is a bad design and when it is not

Comment: @Martijn if I rename to just "byIndex", whouldn't it be misleading on which arguments the functions takes ? it's like the function only takes an "index" parameter

Comment: People are gonna need to see what this function does anyway. Apart from that, it deletes an error by index -> deleteErrorByIndex. You dont "delete an error by an error and index". That would imply that I can input an specific error, which would than be removed if it also matches the provided index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could decouple and create separate methods for example:

```
deleteSignatureErrorsByIndex(index: number){
        this.SignatureErrors.splice(index, 1);
    }

deleteSignatureErrorsByIndex(index: number){
        this.ArErrors.splice(index, 1);
    }


deleteEnrSyncErrorByIndex(index: number){
        this.EnrSyncError.splice(index, 1);

}
```

that being said, it's just a suggestion. having two function params is fine, it's the `if else` part that is dirty.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I caouldn't separate methods because, where I need this functions, I don't know which type will be the error, so I won't know which function I need to call

Comment: Nevermind I found a way to know which function to call, thanks !

Comment: @AmaniteLaurine happy it helped but I hope you understand the reason why moved the ifelse from a single function to probably a higher level.

Comment: Yes thank you ! I thank of doing that before but I abandoned this solution before really digging on how I should implement it, it is far better now